# Ambiguous column name 'ProductNumber'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can't figure out why my question 3 is getting the error mentioned above.

Below is my code

```
/* Question 1 */
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS 
( 
    CustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    CustFirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    CustLastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    CustStreetAddress VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    CustCity VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    CustState VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL, 
    CustZipCode INT NOT NULL, 
    CustAreaCode INT NOT NULL, 
    CustPhoneNumber VARCHAR (26) NOT NULL
);  

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES 
( 
    EmployeeID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    EmpFirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    EmpLastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    EmpCity VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL, 
    EmpState VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL, 
    EmpZipCode INT NOT NULL, 
    EmpAreaCode INT NOT NULL, 
    EmpPhoneNumber VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL, 
    EmpBirthDate DATE NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE ORDERS
( 
    OrderNumber INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    OrderDate DATE NOT NULL, 
    ShipDate DATE NOT NULL, 
    CustomerID INT NOT NULL, 
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL, 

    FOREIGN KEY(EmployeeID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEES(EmployeeID), 
    FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES CUSTOMERS(CustomerID)
); 

CREATE TABLE CATEGORIES
( 
    CategoryID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    CategoryDescription VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
(
    ProductNumber INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    ProductName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    ProductDescription VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    RetailPrice INT NOT NULL, 
    QuantityOnHand INT NOT NULL, 
    CategoryID INT NOT NULL, 

    FOREIGN KEY(CategoryID) REFERENCES CATEGORIES (CategoryID)
);    

CREATE TABLE ORDER_DETAILS
( 
    OrderNumber INT NOT NULL, 
    ProductNumber INT NOT NULL, 
    QuotedPrice INT NOT NULL, 
    QuantityOrdered INT NOT NULL, 

    PRIMARY KEY (OrderNumber, ProductNumber), 
    FOREIGN KEY (OrderNumber) REFERENCES ORDERS(OrderNumber), 
    FOREIGN KEY(ProductNumber) REFERENCES PRODUCTS(ProductNumber)
);   

CREATE TABLE VENDORS
(
    VendorID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    VendName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    VendStreetAddress VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    VendCity VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    VendState VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL, 
    VendFaxNumber VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    VendWebPage VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    VendEmailAddress VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_VENDORS
(
    ProductNumber INT NOT NULL, 
    VendorID INT NOT NULL, 
    WholeSalePrice INT NOT NULL,
    DaysToDeliver INT NOT NULL, 

    PRIMARY KEY(ProductNumber, VendorID), 
    FOREIGN KEY(ProductNumber) REFERENCES PRODUCTS(ProductNumber), 
    FOREIGN KEY(VendorID) REFERENCES Vendors(VendorID)
); 

/* QUESTION 2 */

SELECT 
    OrderDate, CustFirstName, CustLastName
FROM 
    CUSTOMERS C, ORDERS O
WHERE 
    C.CustomerID = O.OrderNumber; 

/* QUESTION 3 */

SELECT 
    ProductNumber, WholeSalePrice, VendName 
FROM 
    PRODUCTS P, PRODUCT_VENDORS PV, VENDORS V 
WHERE 
    P.PRODUCTNUMBER = PV.ProductNumber AND PV.VendorID = V.VendorID;
```

I got the error

> Ambiguous column name 'ProductNumber'

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 4):

Because there are two table have column name of `ProductNumber` in your query you need to tell DB engine which column you want to get.

Also, use `JOIN` instead of `,` comma `CROSS JOIN`, because `Join` is more clear than a comma on the relationship between the two tables

```
SELECT PV.ProductNumber, WholeSalePrice, VendName 
FROM PRODUCTS P 
JOIN PRODUCT_VENDORS PV ON P.PRODUCTNUMBER = PV.ProductNumber
JOIN VENDORS V ON PV.VendorID = V.VendorID;
```

Comment: Also, it's good practice to preface all your columns with the table name or table prefix when joining multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your query stipulates `SELECT ProductNumber` From two tables that both have ProductNumber. In the SELECT columns list, prefix ProductNumber with the table name from which you want to receive the data.

also, Have a look at your question 2. I don't think you really want to join customer id to order number, and you should use `JOIN` syntax intead of joining in the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

Ambiguous error means that you are calling a certain field in which exist in both Table and the SQL has no idea where to get it. See, with your query, you're just literally calling the `ProductNumber` field in which the SQL has no idea where to get it since there are `ProductNumber` fields on both Tables, and you didn't specify any table.

so it is better when you have same column in multiple tables use table preface 1st then column like table1.col1,table2.col2
so in your case

```
 SELECT p.ProductNumber, WholeSalePrice, v.VendName     
   FROM PRODUCTS P join 
  PRODUCT_VENDORS PV  on P.PRODUCTNUMBER = PV.ProductNumber //
  join   VENDORS V on PV.VendorID = V.VendorID //use join instead your's
```